# Is it correct to put STO right before each email in the journey?

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, einstein

STO uses a Machine learning algorithm to decide what time is a perfect send time for each contact that enters the journey, hence increasing the open rate for each email.

So my question is, is it correct to put STO right before each email in the journey? (Except for Thank you email).

Thank you.

Comment: my question back is, how do you define "correct"? :)

Comment: Hi Jonas, thank you for your reply. I would say that I "thought" it is correct to put the STO before each email since it gonna decide what time is the best to send for each contact. However, I am not pretty sure that my "thought" was correct or not :) That's why I asked for experience from all the experts here in Stack Exchange for a more proper to do this. What is your opinion on this ?

Comment: What I meant is, what do you expect to happen? if you don't want static send times but your journey mails should rely on what Einstein thinks is best for each recipient - sure, go for it. And yes, you have to do that for each email separately. Is the Einstein data plausible? That depends on the historic sample that Einstein has to work with. There are ways that data could be skewed e.g. because your past sendouts were always on the same day and the "best time" would be likely close to that time, just because you never tried another :)

Comment: okay. I have my answer now. Thank you for your help Jonas! :D